# Best way to display data out of a database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, android-imagebutton

I attached an image of an application. You see there something like a ListView, but with multiple columns and with images inside the "clickable" buttons.

[image]

Does someone of you know, how this guy has done this? I did some research and I didn't came to a conclusion on how to get something like this done.

Is it even a ListView or is it something completely different?

I want to do something similar, but the amount of buttons can vary which is my problem. A ListView would work, but it looks pretty ugly compared to the example in the image. ImageButton would also work (I think), but you should be able to display any amount of them.

Comment: use gridview with custom layout....

Comment: @sabeersas Sounds interesting, I will take a closer look on that. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you create three vertically oriented linear layouts and populate each with a list and lay them side by side, this is very easily achievable. The layout might look something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:weight="1.0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:weight="1.0"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView3" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:weight="1.0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:weight="1.0"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView2" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:weight="1.0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:weight="1.0"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView1" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The widths are set in this, and it all depends on how you would want the final layout to look, but you would probably want to give them all equal weight in order have them equally spread on the screen. After this you can just use an adapter in your java code, and populate the listview after getting it by id. Then, you will also need a layout to represent each individual listitem and that will be custom and will have an image and text

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. :) But you use 3 ListViews, which means, I would have to split my "ResultSet" from the database into 3 parts (if I got that right). Isn't there a more specific solution?

Comment: Yes, you can also use a grid view but I would prefer this in terms of being cleaner and more easily customized.